# Override tick interval calculation in Highcharts?

Tags: highcharts

Highcharts does a great job figuring out appropriate tick intervals.

However, I have a "duration" series (in ms), which I format e.g. like "3y 6M" or "1d 3h" or "3h 30min" for display. Because Highcharts is optimizing the tick intervals for the ms value (e.g. 10,000,000ms), I end up with awkward values such as [ 2h 46min 40s, 5h 33min 20s, 8h 20min ] rather than [ 3h, 6h, 9h ].

Can I get Highcharts to prefer multiples of certain values (e.g. 1000, 60 * 1000, 60 * 60 * 1000 etc)? I'd rather not have to calculate the exact tick interval myself (depends on chart size etc).

[image: unformated y-axis values]
[image: formatted y-axis values]

Comment: Are you using `type: datetime`?

Comment: There's no datetime involved, just a string category label, and an integer duration value (milliseconds).

Comment: and you're saying that you don't want to calibrate `tickInterval`? I'm unclear as to how you *DO* want the interval to be; just rounded off or something?

Comment: Yes, instead of setting a `tickInterval` (ugly as I'd need to analyze the data and handle resizing etc), I'd rather override the code that is used to calculate the tick intervals--if Highcharts lets me do that.

Comment: You can dynamically create your own variable to use for the `tickInterval` value. i.e. `tickInverval: $myCalculatedValue`. other than that, you might want to try a `datetime` axis which allows you to set a `pointInvterval` such as 1 day or 1 hour, etc.

Comment: Thanks, but as mentioned above I'm looking for a solution other than setting the `tickInterval` explicitly. Highcharts can figure out how how many ticks to draw, but instead of using numbers that are multiples of 10, 100, 1000 etc (or whatever the built-in logic is), I'd like to provide a custom strategy (e.g. use multiples of 1000, 60*1000, 60*60*1000 etc). It's possible that this can't be done right now, in which case I hope someone from Highcharts reads this question :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should consider using datetime axis for yAxis.  For example: http://jsfiddle.net/jRGvs/

```
    yAxis: {
        type: 'datetime'
    },

    series: [{
        type: 'column',
        name: 'Column',
        data: [Date.UTC(1970, 0, 1, 2, 30), 
               Date.UTC(1970, 0, 1, 1, 45), 
               Date.UTC(1970, 0, 1, 4, 10), 
               Date.UTC(1970, 0, 1, 3, 30)]
    }]
```

Comment: This approach only works for durations < 24h; a duration of 2 days for example is labelled Jan 3...

Comment: Using a formatter won't help, see my comment on @strikers solution.

Comment: Thanks, this does indeed work! The tick values passed to the formatter appear to be properly rounded, so they can be formatted either as seconds, hours, days etc.

Answer (score 0):

you can go with label > formatter for yAxis,

here you can write a routine which will handle the text/value to be displayed beside the grid line. but the thing is you cannot override the tick interval from here.

Comment: That's how the 2nd chart above was done. I could just have the formatter do the rounding, but then I'd have ticks labelled [3h, 6h, 8h], which might seem a bit odd...

Comment: was the axis type set to datetime? if it is set to datetime  then you can handle it from highcharts itself

Comment: Regarding datetime, see my comment on the answer provided by @pawel-fus